# 2 WiFi routers on one network - Not able to override DNS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

I have 2 WiFi routers on my home network.

1. *TP Link*, which is connected from ISP modem. IP - 192.168.0.1
2. *Netgear*, which is connected from the *TP Link* via the cable.IP - 192.168.0.2

I am able to connect to both of them and have internet connectivity also. Now, I need to override the DNS settings of the Netgear. In the Netgear *Smart Wizard*, in its Basic settings menu, I have changed the DNS. But there is no effect. I have checked it from https://www.dnsleaktest.com/.

So what am I missing here. Please see the image of the Router 2 settings:

[image: Router 2 settings]

But the DNS in the TP Link(first router) is overridden, it is working.

I also tried with Netgear as Router 1 and TP link as Router 2, but the issue is still there. So there must be something obvious which I am missing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to the fact, the grammatical mistakes that exist, makes this question extremely hard to understand.

Comment: Did you run the DNS leak test from the router? If so, how exactly? If not, why would you expect the router's DNS settings to affect the test results?

Answer (score 1):

You have these routers on one subnet (best way to do it), so the DNS is held by the TP Link, not the Netgear. This is normal.

If you need two DNS then separate the TP Link into its own subnet.

Comment: Yes, basically, your first router is bridging to the second, so it's the first router's DNS that's important, not the second's, unless you also connect it directly to your modem, creating a new subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I fixed it this way
- TP Link( main router) ip - 192.168.0.1
- Netgear(router 2) ip - 192.168.1.1

Connected the cable from LAN port of router 1 to WAN port of router 2. Then I override the dns in router 2. Thats it :)